# Why does my Exception get lost?

Tags: c#

I use the following code to call a web method and get some info. To tidy things up a bit and get some code reuse, I introduced the InvokeWebMethod routine.

```
private T InvokeWebMethod<T>(webServiceDelegate d)
{
    return (T)base.invokeWebMethod(d);
}
internal XmlElement GetInfo(string url)
{
    return this.InvokeWebMethod<XmlElement>(() => { return this.myService.GetInfo(url); });
}
```

If the web method does not exist on the server, a 404 Exception is raised inside the delegate. 
The bit that I don't understand, is that the Lambda function ignores the 404 exception and instead raises an XmlElement Cast exception.

Can any one explain to me why the 404 Exception isn't raised up the stack until it is handled?

Thanks

Comment: XmlElement Cast exception is a Runtime exception before it is fully executed. And if given that casting problem is resolved it would eventually lead to 404 exception which is more of a web server exception?

Comment: I have little idea what `InvokeWebMethod` is, but I suspect that whatever it is, it's trying to convert the HTTP response into an XML structure, and the 404 response is, as one would expect, not formatted in XML.

Comment: Kirk Woll, Why would it try to convert the HTTP response to XML? When the 404 Exception occurs, shouldn't it jump up the stack to the first Try/Catch ?

Comment: Edper, Can you explain that a bit more? Aren't both exceptions Runtime exceptions? the 404 Exception occurs first, so I don't understand why it reports the Cast exception.

Comment: @Matt, like I said, that entirely depends on how `InvokeWebMethod` is implemented.  If you were using `HttpClient`, for example, no exception would be thrown unless calling `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta check the InnerException property of the exception you are getting, chances are the 404 exception is somewhere down the stack.